# Unify a JQuery Script and build in a check

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to consolidate this script a bit.. They both do almost the same thing.

When a button is clicked, it opens a box. It might be tough, but what I DON'T want to happen is when one box is open (defined as the #signincontainer and #searchcontainer) I don't want the other one to be able to be open as well. I am not good enough to be able to build this into this script.

Also, is it possible to make it so when the user clicks somewhere else on the page other than inside the box, it closes the box?

Here's the script. You guys rock!

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".folderContent").hide();
  });

  $(".signin").click(function(event) {
    var folderContent = $(".folderContent");


    var folderContentShown = folderContent.css("display") != "none";

    var clickedFolder = $(this);
    clickedFolder.parent("#signincontainer").after(folderContent);

    $("body").find("#container").not(clickedFolder).each(function() {
        if (!folderContentShown) $(this).not("#signincontainer").animate( {
            opacity: 0.50
        }, "slow");
        else $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1.00
        }, "slow");

  $('#wrapper2').css('overflow','hidden');                      
    });

    //clickedFolder.animate({opacity: folderContentShown ? 1.00 : 0.70}, "fast");
    folderContent.slideToggle();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});


$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchfolderContent").hide();
  });

  $(".search").click(function(event) {
    var searchfolderContent = $(".searchfolderContent");


    var searchfolderContentShown = searchfolderContent.css("display") != "none";

    var clickedsearchFolder = $(this);
    clickedsearchFolder.parent("#searchcontainer").after(searchfolderContent);

    $("body").find("#container").not(clickedsearchFolder).each(function() {
        if (!searchfolderContentShown) $(this).not("#searchcontainer").animate( {
            opacity: 0.50
        }, "slow");
        else $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1.00
        }, "slow");

  $('#wrapper2').css('overflow','hidden');                      
    });

    //clickedFolder.animate({opacity: folderContentShown ? 1.00 : 0.70}, "fast");
    searchfolderContent.slideToggle();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I see two questions.  First, to only show if another is not already shown you can do something like this.  Assumes there is a shared class on the things you are clicking.

```
$(".clickything").click(function(){
    if($(".clickything").is(":visible")){
         // do what you want to do if one is already visible
    }else{
         // do whatever you want to do if no others are visible
    }
});
```

The question of clicking elsewhere on the page.  There are multiple ways of doing this.  One way would be to add a click handler to the body that hidesthem, but then in the click handler for you clickable items you add event.stopPropagation().  Somethign like this:

```
$("body").click(function(){
   $(".clickything").hide();
});

$(".clickything").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   //do your other stuff
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SeynY/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're looking for is very similar to the functionality provided by a "lightbox" solution, such as [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).  This allows you to have certain divs show up when certain links/DOM elements are clicked.  You can view some examples [here](http://fancybox.net/blog).  All design is via CSS, which allows you to modify it to your liking (including opacity).